# Lme error: "Error in reStruct"

Tags: r, mixed-models

4 beehives were equipped with sensors that collected temp, humidity, pressure, decibels inside the hive. these are the response variables.

the treatment was wifi exposure, the experimental groups were exposed to wifi from day 1 to day 20, then again from day 35-45, and data was collected until day day 54. n of hives = 4, n of data collected by sensors in each hive = ~million.

I am having difficulties running mixed effects models.

there is a data frame of all the hives' response variables.

```
names(Hives)
[1] "time"           "dht22_t"        "dht11_t"        "dht22_h"       
[5] "dht11_h"        "db"             "pa"             "treatment_hive"
[9] "wifi"
```

time is in "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", dht11/22_t/h are either temperature and humidity data.  "wifi" is a dichotomous variable (1=on 0=off) that corresponds to the time of exposure, and treatment hive is another dichotomous variable for the hives exposed to wifi (1=exposure, 0=control).

Here is the error i am getting.

```
attach(Hives)
model2 = lme(pa_t~wifi*treatment_hive, random=time, na.action=na.omit, method="REML",)

Error in reStruct(random, REML = REML, data = NULL) : 
Object must be a list or a formula
```

Here is a sample of the code:

```
    time    dht22_t dht11_t dht22_h dht11_h db  pa  treatment_hive  wifi
1   01/09/2014 15:19    NA      NA  NA      NA  51.75467    NA      0   1
2   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  59.8    44  55.27682    100672  0   1
3   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  60.3    44  54.81995    100675  0   1
4   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  60.9    44  54.14134    100671  0   1
5   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  61.1    44  53.88574    100672  0   1
6   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  61.2    44  53.68800    100680  0   1
```

R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i486-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.8.9   proto_0.3-9.2   reshape_0.8.4   plyr_1.7.1      nlme_3.1-104
[6] lme4_0.999999-0 Matrix_1.0-6    lattice_0.20-6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a variety of issues here, some relevant to programming (StackOverflow) but probably the statistical issues (suitable for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) or `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org`) are more important.

**tl;dr** If you just want to avoid the error I think you need `random=~1|hive` (whatever your hive-indicator variable is) to fit a model where baseline response (intercept) varies across hives, but I'd encourage you to read on ...

- can we have a (small!) [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) ?
- don't use `attach(Hives)`, use `data=Hives` in your `lme()` call (not necessarily the problem, but [much] better practice)
- with only 4 hives it is a bit questionable whether a random effect specification across hives will work (although with a million observations you might get away with it)
- the random effect must be composed of a *categorical* (factor) grouping variable; in your case I think "hive" is the grouping variable, but I can't tell from your question which variable identifies hives
- you should almost certainly have a model that accounts for trends in time and variation in time trends across hives, i.e. a random-slopes model, which would be expressed as `formula=...~...+time, random=~time|hive` (where the `...` represents the bits of your existing model)
- you'll have to convert time to something sensible to use it in your model (see `?strptime` or the `lubridate` package), something like seconds/minutes/hours from starting time might be most sensible.  (What is your time resolution?  Do you have multiple sensors per hive, in which case you should consider fitting a random effect of sensor as well?)
- with millions of data points your model fit is likely to be very slow; you might want to consider the `lme4` package
- with millions of data points everything is going to be statistically significant, and very sensitive to aspects of the model that don't appear in the data, such as (1) nonlinear trends in time (e.g. consider fitting additive models of the time trends with `mgcv::gamm` or the `gamm4` package); (2) temporal autocorrelation (consider adding a `correlation` parameter in your `lme` model).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate it a lot. Reproducible code was edited into the OP. Despite having >million data points, having n=4 (2 control/2 experimental) is statistically dubious. Currently only the column $treatment_hive specifies treatment vs control but not individual hives. Should it? Time resolution: about 15 points were logged per minute be the sensors.

Comment: Also, after editing in your suggestions, i haven't figured out how to convert time from starting point. what would the code look like?

Comment: About choosing the correct model, it is too determine if wifi exposure had an effect on the experimental hives. Also, I am thinking of reducing the data because my 32bit machine can't handle running the models. Like taking data points every half hour instead of several times a minute, for instance.

Comment: How many sensors per hive do you have?  Even with samples every hour I only get 54*4*24*60=311040 total samples -- are you really taking samples every 5 seconds?

Comment: If your programming problem is solved (i.e. if you can get *any* model to run in `lme` with a small subset of your data), I would strongly recommend you that you accept this answer and post a version of your question on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yes, samples were continuously taken about 19 times a minute. the project was a proof of concept. I will post a question on CrossValidated shortly. Thank you for your input and pointing in this direction.

Comment: That's a CrossValidated question ... without more context it's hard to answer, but I don't see what you need one for.  Overfitting due to non-independence and inflated type I error due to multiple comparisons are only loosely analogous.

Comment: Oh it was a technique used in a similar hive monitoring paper that i was unsure about. I am thinking about running non-linear mixed models and a cosinor analysis to better fit the circadian data